# Persistent location-based reminder

Tags: ios, reminders, geolocation

I want to set a permanent reminder in iOS that will fire every time I leave the house to remind me to check that I've locked the door.  I can set a location-based reminder that triggers when I leave, but it seems to be a one-shot deal (and I don't want to have to set a reminder to remind me to set another reminder!)

It does seem that there's an ability to set a scheduled reminder that fires every day at a given time and is also location-based, but I don't think this is what I'm looking for due to requiring to have to set a time too.  I don't think this is going to fire off if I'm already outside before the reminder's time comes.

Is it possible to set up an event that fires off every time you leave a location and not just once?  If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out the solution was ridiculously simple.  If you never check the item off the reminder list as done then it fires every time you leave the house.

The only issue I'm having with it now is that it doesn't fire until I'm a considerable distance from the house, and it seems the smallest radius you can set on it is 100m.

Answer (score 2):

You can set up repeating reminders based on location using several different methods. Workflow and Shortcuts are native iOS apps that have functions for reminders based on location. I do not recall if they can be triggered automatically or have to be manually triggered.

You could also use a third party app/service such as [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/) which supports repeating triggers. Use the [location](https://ifttt.com/location) service connected to a [notification](https://ifttt.com/if_notifications) service to create your reminder.